# Clear textfield based onchanged (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

```
TextField(
    inputFormatters: [
     new FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
     RegExp('[0-9]')),
    ],
    hintText: 'some text'
    title: '',
    editingController: controllers[31],
    value: somenumber,
    onChange: (value) {
      if (num.parse(value) <= 3000 &&
        num.parse(value) >= 30) {
        // save some data
      }else{
      controllers[31].clear(),
     },
   ),
```

so above is a textfield with onchange, right now the textfield does not clear if i put outside of the range, is it possible to clear the textfield based onchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `TextField()` you are using part of a plugin? The properties look a bit odd compared with the latest stable release of Flutter.

Here's an example that clears the text:

```
TextEditingController textEditingController = new TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container(
      child: TextField(
        inputFormatters: [
          new FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
        ],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'some text',
        ),
        controller: textEditingController,
        onChanged: (value) {
          if (value.length <= 10) {
            // something
          } else {
            textEditingController.clear();
          }
        }
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create TextEditingController for your text field and then assign it to the controller property of TextField.

```
// create controller
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
```

```
// assign it to TextField controller property
TextField(
    controller : _controller
    // your other properties
)
```

then to clear the text

```
// clear text
_controller.clear();
``
```

Answer (score 0):

U can also do this :

```
TextEditingController textEditingController = new TextEditingController();
Function onchange;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container(
      child: TextField(
        inputFormatters: [
          new FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
        ],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'some text',
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                widget.onchanged('');
                controller.clear();
              },
        ),
        controller: textEditingController,
        onChanged: (value) => onchange(value)

        }
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you can add some explanation along with the code.

Comment: the onChanged method has parameters String we pass it an empty string and then I cleared the TextForm with controller.clear()